# Create Progress wheel in CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to create a progress wheel in html and css, if necessary than `jQuery` also. I create a wheel but problem is that how can I set the length of the borders according to given percentage.
Here is Code:

```css
.loader {
  border: 16px solid #f3f3f3;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top: 16px solid #3498db;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
}
```

```html
<div class="loader"></div>
```

It create a circle and blue border on it but I want like the below image.
[image: Progress Wheel with precentage]

Comment: please provide your code in fiddle.

Comment: @ShivkumarKondi It's there as a snippet, what do you need a fiddle for?

Comment: Please don't use CSS for things like this. SVG is a much better alternate and this thread could help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35132864/progress-circle-draw-a-small-arc-at-the-end-tip-of-the-circle-more/35134680#35134680. It is slightly different but should guide you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [radial progress bar](http://codepen.io/akZhy/pen/RROqPa) that i made. I have updated it to suit your needs.

The fill percentage is determined by the `transform` `rotate` value given to `.pure-css .semi.right .circle` and `.pure-css .semi.left .circle`

```css
.pure-css {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #fff;
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
}

.pure-css .semi {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index:2;
  transform:rotate(30deg)
}

.pure-css .semi.left{
  transform-origin:100% 50%;
 }
.pure-css .semi.right{
  transform-origin:0% 50%;
 }
.pure-css .semi.right .circle {
  border-top-left-radius: 150px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 150px;
  border-right: 0;
  transform: rotate(181deg) translate(-100%, 0);
  animation: rotate 4s linear forwards;
  transform-origin: 0% 50%;
}

.pure-css .semi.left .circle {
  border-top-right-radius: 150px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 150px;
  border-left: 0;
  transform: rotate(36deg) translate(100%, 0);
  animation: rotate2 4s linear forwards;
  transform-origin: 100% 50%;
  animation-delay: 42s;
}

.pure-css .semi .circle {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 50px solid #4ec9aa;
}

.pure-css .text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 28px;
  color:#28645d;
  text-align:center;
}
.pure-css .shade {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform:scale(.9,.9);
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 30px solid #e7ebee;
}
```

```html
<div class="rp">
    <div class="pure-css">
      <div class="semi left">
        <div class="circle"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="semi right">
        <div class="circle"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="text">
        <span class="num">Goal<br><b>20,000$</b></span>
      </div>
      <div class="shade"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

To change the fill value give

```
.pure-css .semi.left .circle{
    transform: rotate(xdeg) translate(-100%, 0);
}
.pure-css .semi.right.circle{
    transform: rotate(xdeg) translate(-100%, 0);
}
```

where x is a value between 0 and 180 (optional) giving 180 to `.semi.right` will fill half the circle and 180 to `.semi-left` will fill the full circle.

To fill according to a percentage value,for filling < `50%` set the `transform` of `.semi.right .circle` to `percentage * 360 / 100 deg` and for filling > `50%` set the transform of `.semi.left .circle to 180 - (percentage * 360/100) deg`.

For determining the start and end position of the fill value

```
.pure-css .semi {
   transform:rotate(xdeg)
}
```

Comment: How can I change the percentage value like if I want to set it in 40%, or 80% or on 100% it must be complete circle

Comment: @AzeemHaider I have updated the code, it is now filled 60%, for filling < 50 set the transform of `.semi.right .circle` to `percentage * 360 / 100 deg` and for filling > 50 set the transform of `.semi.left .circle` to `180 - (percentage * 360/100) deg`

Comment: Thanks for your work but can you please let know how I can fill up according to my requirements ? Like using javascript. Which values I need to change ?

Comment: If you are using javascript, i would suggest using the plugin in that codepen @AzeemHaider

Comment: if I use css then what Values I need to change ?